# remove background from Bottomsheet android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout, bottom-sheet

I have created bottomsheet dialog which work great when it is in portait mode but it shows white backgrund when screen in landscape mode
[attaching the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDn5g.jpg)

here is code that i used
xml: https://github.com/windowschares/test/blob/main/bottomsheet.xml
java code :

```
 final BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_bottomsheet);
    LinearLayout sheetView =findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_id);
    SwitchCompat disable_pip = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.disable_pip);
    SwitchCompat Enable_fullscreen = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.Enable_fullscreen);
    ImageView external_player = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.external_player);
    bottomSheetDialog.show();
```

Comment: Change your first LinearLayout with  and Try once--  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_id"
        android:background="@color/Home_Background"
        android:orientation="vertical">

Comment: yes i tried that solution but actually i dont want them to be match parent i want them to fit like a how we see in popup window. exact example is how we see in disneyplus hotstar settings option.

Comment: simple words, i want them to be a small bottomsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May it help you to achieve your output-
Please change xml images/colors/text/icons as per your requirement
XML File--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:drawableLeftCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pip_disable_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:text="Disable Pip"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/disable_pip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="160dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/full_screen_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:text="Enable Fullscreen"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/Enable_fullscreen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="120dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/play_mx"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Play_via_MX"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:text="Play with Mxplayer"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/external_player"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And style.xml/theme.xml

Add this line in your parent theme

```
<item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/CustomBottomSheetDialog</item>
```

and add this custom style in your style.xml/theme.xml file

```
<style name="CustomBottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheet</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomBottomSheet" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet">
        <item name="behavior_peekHeight">512dp</item>
        <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog" parent="">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">16dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: thanks for your wonderful help and thankyou for taking time in checking my code. i came to conclusion that, its not possible to achieve that effect shown in hotstar (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUaOa.png) so i have plan to convert them to horizontal and add three more items to fill the gap

Answer (score 0):

The LinearLayout with id `bottom_sheet_id` is set to a fixed size which is why it's not taking up the whole width of its parent. Set it to `match_parent` to fix this.

Comment: thanks for your answer but yes i tried that ,https://ibb.co/2MLDg9W showing like this but i want it like fit to height and width no need those extra white portions

Comment: i want to achive bottomsheet like how we see in disney plus hotstar's settings

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your wonderful help and thankyou for taking time in checking my code. i came to conclusion that, its not possible to achieve that effect shown in hotstar (i.stack.imgur.com/kUaOa.png) so i have plan to convert them to horizontal and add three more items to fill the gap